# Determining eigenvalues and eigenvectors in R

Tags: r, multicollinearity, eigenvalues

```
x<-model.matrix(d) [,-1]
e<-eigen(t(x) %*% x)
e

values
[1] 1174600.548   21261.741   16133.842    6206.181    1856.894
```

First my $\alpha_1=1174600.548$, but how which is the orthogonal eigenvector to $\lambda~ 1=$. How do I interpret these values below?

```
vectors
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]      [,5]
[1,] -0.05483536  0.01923863 -0.16111563 -0.19334497    0.96606544
[2,] -0.30111461  0.90745209 -0.24543862  0.15349803   -0.04537559
[3,] -0.59738921 -0.06197220  0.05081398 -0.77741824   -0.17978986
[4,] -0.73385464 -0.35415236 -0.06415612  0.57195569    0.06916759
[5,] -0.10443454  0.21655517  0.95241985  0.08685415    0.16598214
```

then I found the condition numbers as follows:

```
> sqrt(e\$val[1]/e\$val)  
[1]  1.000000  7.432684  8.532498 13.757290 25.150782
```

which K<30 so no multicollinearity. Is there anything else I should be observing with these values?

Answer (score 1):

What is the scale of the columns in your model matrix? If the scale differs widely, one often uses the correlation matrix, rather than the covariance - and I am assuming here that your columns were centered about the mean.

The first eigenvector often represents overall size. This may be more or less true in your case - all coefficients have the same sign - but they clearly favour variables 2, 3, and 4. (or perhaps that's due to the scaling of the variables.) The second eigenvector is forcible orthogonal to the first; it appears to be comparing the 2nd variable to the 4th - with a bit of 5 thrown in. You often find that sort of thing - each subsequent eigenvector "throws in" what was omitted from the others. The 3rd compares 1 and 2 to variable 5.

The last eigenvector is basically pulling out variable 1, which was downweighted by the first eigenvector.

96% of the variation goes to the first eigenvalue, which suggests that your data are fairly well summarized by a weighted mean - the rest being orthogonal noise.

Does this make sense from what you know of the problem?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the correction, I am not familiar with R syntax so I didn't know that %*% means $A^TA$. I removed my comment.

Comment: I understand the first part but the 1st column of the values is the first eigenvector?